# Evidence of cannabis exposure causing schizophrenia?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, psychopharmacology

I've heard that cannabis exposure during teenage years increases the probability of developing schizophrenia-like symptoms later in life. What evidence is there that this is causal and not correlational?

Current references I'm reading and will try to form into an answer:

- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/26733534/
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/28392208/
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/28285022/
- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/28443616/

Comment: A couple of things: 1) Psychotic patients make more use of cannabis than non-psychotic patients 2) people who consume cannabis between 15-18 are more likely to display psychotic symptoms at 26 3) relevant paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2864503/

Comment: 1. your best bet would be twin studies (concordance rate between MZ and DZ twins with/without cannabis exposure. 2. since i last checked, there is at least one study with evidence that cannabis has anti-psychotic properties in a group of treatment refractory individuals with schizophrenia. 3. you should clarify your term "schizophrenia-like" -- do you also consider schizotypy to fit this criterion.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered a study relating to a **longitudinal study** of a cohort of 45 570 Swedish conscripts covering a 15 year difference in between the first testing of and after. They covered the Swedish conscripts who had taken cannabis ( Who used cannabis on more than '50 occasions' )  and the others who haven't and came to the conclusion that the subjects that taken cannabis had a higher likelihood of developing schizophrenic symptoms than their counterparts. In their own words,

> "Persistence of the association after allowance for other psychiatric
> illness and social background indicated that cannabis is an
> independent risk factor for schizophrenia"

The study is here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0140673687926201